# pieTest - Mutation Test failure

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit5, spring-test, mutation-testing

All, There is an issue while running mutation test cases.

Getting the mutation test case failures as follows:

removed call to java/util/List::sort → SURVIVED
removed call to java/util/List::forEach → SURVIVED

The code:

```
List<CustomClass> data;//address is the field in the CustomClass
UseCase useCase; //setEventBus is the method
   data.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(CustomClass::getAddress));
     
   data.forEach(frame -> useCase.setEventBus(frameList, data.getAddress()));
```

I have written couple of unit test cases but mutants survived. Can anyone help here for this problem?

Comment: I also do my first steps with mutation testing, so it's just a guess: Your test is still green, even when the `sort` and `forEach` is removed from code. Write a test, that fails when you remove one of these calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The failed mutation cases are solved.

removed call to java/util/List::sort → SURVIVED:

Added the test case for the below line
data.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(CustomClass::getAddress));
The test case is added to store the unsorted data in 'data' object.